Mapping Text Analyzing Results to Predefined Outputs in Conversational AI Using CrewAI Library
I'm currently developing a conversational AI system utilizing the CrewAI Python library to analyze user input and extract the object and action. While the initial processing works well, I'm encountering difficulty in further processing the identified object and action to map them to predefined outputs.
For example, given the user input "Please, brew me a cup of joe", the system correctly identifies the action as "brew" and the object as "cup of joe". However, I need to map this to predefined outputs such as {"action": "make", "object": "coffee"}.
Here's a snippet of what I'm aiming for:
predefined_actions = ["make"]
predifined_objects = ["coffee"]

user_input = "Please, brew me a cup of joe"

output = {"action": "brew", "object": "cup of joe"}
mapped_output = {"action": "make", "object": "coffee"}

I'm seeking guidance on the steps I should take to achieve this mapping effectively. Specifically, I'd appreciate insights on:

Strategies for mapping identified actions and objects to predefined outputs.
Tools or techniques that could streamline this mapping process, especially within the context of the CrewAI library.
Suggestions for improving the efficiency or accuracy of the mapping process.

Any assistance or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, the code repository for my project can be found here for further context.
Thank you!
I attempted to create two additional CrewAI agents alongside the main agent responsible for analyzing the text. One agent was dedicated to mapping the action, while the other focused on mapping the object. However, this approach did not yield the expected output. The agents seemed to struggle with providing accurate mappings, and there was also a persistent issue where the agents favored certain tools instead of the intended mappings.
Despite these efforts, I haven't been able to achieve the desired mapping functionality effectively. Therefore, I'm seeking guidance on alternative approaches or adjustments that could help improve the accuracy and reliability of the mapping process within the context of the CrewAI library.
